# Is it possible to use GMap.Net Windows Form dll in WPF?

Tags: wpf, gmap.net

I want to use GMap.net in my WPF project.
Unfortunately I couldn't find any good references to use GMap.net in WPF like [this source](http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-beginners-tutorial-adding-clickable-markers-to-your-map-updates-for-vs2015-and-gmap-1-7.html) for windows form and for each part I have to search a lot to use it.
My first question is that is there any good source on how to use GMap.net in WPF?
My second question is, that I see in SO some one has told that had used GMap.NET.WindowsForms.dll in WPF instead of GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.dll. Is it possible? If yes, how?
I added GMap.NET.WindowsForms.dll ,GMap.NET.Core.dll and System.Windows.Forms to my project and add below code to Window_Loaded event but there is no map when the project run:

```
        GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl gmap = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl();
        gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        gmap.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(48.8589507, 2.2775175);
        gmap.Width = 500;
        gmap.Height = 500;
        gmap.Zoom = 13;
        gmap.ShowCenter = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any documentation specific to using GMap in WPF, though I didn't look very hard. In any case, the api is very similar. After adding in the NuGet pkg GMap.NET.Presentation into a project, the code you've shown only needs a minor modification:

```
GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapControl gmap = new GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapControl ();
gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
gmap.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng (48.8589507, 2.2775175);
gmap.Width = 500;
gmap.Height = 500;
gmap.Zoom = 13;
gmap.ShowCenter = false;

mainGrid.Children.Add (gmap);
Grid.SetColumn (gmap, 1);
gmap.Margin = new Thickness (10, 200, 10, 10);
```

the last 3 lines assume you are putting this into a Grid control. Change them to match what you are using.

As for your remaining 2 questions... Yes, it is possible to use the Winforms version in a WPF application. Although I have to ask why since it gets a little bit more complicated and limited? But if you must, your code is mostly fine. You will need to add a `WindowsFormsHost` control to your WPF window to host the winforms GMap control. The XAML would be something like this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="wfHost" Margin="10,160,10,10"/>
```

then in your code, after you setup the gmap control, add:

```
wfHost.Child = gmap;
```

and it should work.

One thing I don't think you do is use BOTH WPF and Winforms versions of the GMap library. I got a lot of conflicts and errors when I tried...

Comment: Thank you dear Jeff R. Adding <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="wfHost" Margin="10,160,10,10"/>  helped me to use windows form dll in my wpf project.